# How to optimally sort this array by tag matches and group matches?

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, sorting

I have an array `arr` of entries and I have an `entryA`. My goal is to find the entries in `arr` most related to `entryA`.

I decided to use tag occurrences and groups membership to sort `arr`. I want to minimize time and space as much as possible:

```
# For some entry entryX in array arr:
   entryX.tag_list      #returns the array of tags for entryX
   entryX.groups        #returns the array of groups for entryX
   entryA.user          #returns the user who created entryA

# Similarly, for entryA
   entryA.tag_list      #returns the array of tags for entryA
   entryA.groups        #returns the array of groups for entryA
   entryA.user          #returns the user who created entryA
```

I want to sort the array `arr` such that the entry in `arr` that shares the most number of same groups with `entryA`, the most number of same tags in `entryA.tag_list` and was created by the same user will have precedence and will be positioned at `arr[0]` . So I want to give a factor of 1 for each group shared, 1 for each tag shared, and 2 if created by the same user.

What is the best possible algorithm to achieve this?

Comment: Your question is broad and asking for us to recommend something without enough information. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268519/128421 helps explain the issue. Instead, you should do the research and try implementing your choice, then ask a specific question about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TAG_LIST_UNIT_VALUE = 1
GROUPS_UNIT_VALUE = 1
SAME_USER_VALUE = 2

def score(entryA, entryX)
   TAG_LIST_UNIT_VALUE * (entryA.tag_list & entryX.tag_list).size +
   GROUPS_UNIT_VALUE * (entryA.groups & entryX.groups).size +
   (entryA.user == entryX.user) ? SAME_USER_VALUE : 0
end

arr.sort_by { |entryX| -score(entryA, entryX) }
```

`entryA.tag_list & entryX.tag_list` is an array of the groups common to both `entryA` and `entryX`. Similar for `groups`. The values returned by `score` are negated to make the sort decreasing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to point out that the boolean inside the expression is problematic. Best is to save a variable   USER_WEIGHTED_SUM = (entryA.user == entryX.user) ? SAME_USER_BONUS : 0   and then add this variable to the score. Also having a hash to store both the entries and their score is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Better? btw, USER_WEIGHTES_SUM, because it begins with a capital letter, is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

1. Design a structure to keep `{original_entry_index, closeness_to_A_score}`.
2. Create an array of the above with as many numbers of elements as you entry array and fill-in the `closeness_to_A_score` respectively
3. sort the created array descending by the `closeness_to_A_score`.

O(N) space complexity and O(N*log(N)) time complexity.

Some surprises may pop up when taking the contribution to the score of 'shared tags' and 'shared groups' - if you can store them in hash-sets (best) or sorted sets (good enough) instead of lists (groan!), counting the elements in their intersection will be as fast as reasonable possible.

Comment: Right that s what I thought. And as it s ruby I could just implicitly sort the structure by value and then return a sorted array by just calling  keys on the hash. Thanks

Comment: @codigomonstruo Welcome (though, it is customary on SO to express  thanks by upvoting the answers that helped you or even accepting the one that offers you a solution)

Comment: Haha will do with a thanks will accept answer and upvote it

Answer (score 1):

Post to evolve Adrian answer. You have already described a kind of classifier for items in the array. Now you need to implement it with your rules.

In order to apply it you can use [`Enumerable#sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) which does exactly what Adrian said except for classifying. This method will sort the elements according to the classification grade. Taking into account, that you want the most similar element at the head of the list you need to add `.inverse` to the result array.

One of the possible templates for the solution could look like this

```rb
def classifier_generator(sample)
  lambda do |entry|
    # calculation of similarity based on sample and entry values
  end
end 

grader = classifier_generator(entryA)

arr.sort_by &grader .inverse
```